# Getting device audio output

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, audio

I'm trying to get my Macs main audio output, and tap into it, and then use speech to text on it.

**The part I'm currently stuck on** is getting my Macs main sound output. For example, if I were to go onto `Youtube` and play a video, it outputs the sound to my laptop speakers. I'm trying to tap into that output.

I'm using

```
AVAudioEngine.mainMixerNode
```

However, I dont get any output. I've also tried `AVAudioEngine.outputNode`

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
engine = AVAudioEngine()
let _ = engine.mainMixerNode
engine.prepare()
do {
    try engine.start()
} catch {
    print("Start Error")
    return
}

do {
    let settings = engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0).settings
    print("FileType: \(settings[AVAudioFileTypeKey])") // Returns nil
    self.file = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: settings)
    
    engine.mainMixerNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: nil) { // I've tried with a format and without
        (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer?, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
        do {
            // Buffer must be empty because the CAF audio length is correct, but there's no sound. It's flat.
            try self.file.write(from: buffer!)
        } catch _{
            print("Problem Writing Buffer")
        }
    }
}
```

The above code has `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description` set. (Even though I'm not looking to tap the mic)

The first problem here is that I'm not sure what file type I should use for my output. I've tried `CAF`, but opening it in `GarageBand` produces no sound (although there is length)
I've tried renaming the file to `m4a` and `wav`, but Apple's `Music` just doesn't want to play it.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not a trivial task to get access to the system sound output like this (which is probably a good thing, from a security standpoint).

The solutions will generally involve setting up a 'fake' audio device that audio can get played through instead of the default output device you've chosen. This is the approach, for example, that BlackHole (https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) and the more-elderly SoundFlower (https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) use. Both of those links are to source code that you can start digging through to see how they accomplish this -- again, more in depth than a SO answer warrants.

In terms of the `mainMixerNode` that you're exploring, although the name makes it sound like a system-wide device, it really just controls the mixer for your app's sound. So, although you *could* tap it, it would just give you access to what you're playing. That's why your recorded file is flat -- unless you're playing output, it won't get recorded.